# Can redis cluster multi set command on different slots?

Tags: redis

I know at standalone instance , it works ok .

But at redis cluster, can multi set command on different slots ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO.** You cannot run command in Redis cluster where keys belong to multiple slots.

You can use [hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags) to do [multiple key operations](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#multiple-keys-operations) in cluster mode.